# Show FPS meter Chrome 33

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I think I'm going mad.  I use the FPS meter in Chrome all the time, but I can no longer find it.  If I go into settings in the dev tools it is not there.

Can anyone guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

I am using a Windows PC and Chrome 33.0.1750.117

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to about:flags and enable the the FPS counter there.

You might also need to enable GPU composition on all pages.
I can't enable this on my current machine, so I'm afraid I can't test it myself.

See [this article](http://www.thechromesource.com/tag/chrome-fps-counter/) for more information

Comment: So does this mean that the FPS meter, continuous repainting etc. are no longer in the dev tools settings?  The article was written for Chrome 13.

Comment: I have found the correct answer in the dev tools docs, in short they've moved it.  See my answer for details

Answer (score 33):

Found the answer in the [developer tools docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

They have moved to `Timeline`

Towards the bottom there is a tab called Rendering, this contains all the goodies that were once in settings.

For more info see [Rendering Settings](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/rendering-settings)

Comment: Are there still there? I don't see them on version `39.0.2171.95`

Comment: I see it on `39.0.2171.95`

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to turn it off now until saw your comments.

Comment: I had to enable the Rendering-Tab by clicking on the three dots beside the console tab.

Answer (score 31):

Version 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit)
Update for anyone still looking

1. F12
2. click on 3 dots

   [image: 3 dots img]
3. Click on More tools
4. Click on Rendering settings
5. Then the settings will be available down near the console

   [image: Show FPS meter]

Answer (score 6):

To get an FPS meter Chrome 71 in the year 2019 you can open devtools and then navigate to "More Tools", then select Rendering, which has an FPS meter

Screenshot here

[image: fps tab in chrome]

Comment: I'll just add that using the Performance Profiler also logs framerate which can be easier to browse in detail than the FPS meter which doesn't really log any info.

Answer (score 5):

I found the option from this document: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings

On the main menu bar there is an icon that looks similar to `>≡` that will toggle a bottom-pane off and on that contains the options:

- Show paint rectangles
- Show composited layer borders
- Show FPS meter
- Enable continuous page repainting
- Show potential scroll bottlenecks

Toggle the FPS meter from there.

*Current Chrome version at time of writing `39.0.2171.95`*

Answer (score 2):

press F12, then press esc, a drawer opens at the bottom of the screen, select rendering and then select show FPS meter.

Answer (score 0):

Type `chrome://flags/` in your address bar
Search for `FPS`
Enable/Disable it
Restart Chrome

Comment: This answer does not work in Chrome/-ium versions 62+.