# How to toggle Chrome's FPS meter programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome

After searching, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038065/show-fps-meter-chrome-33) topic, but that's how to enable/show the meter through the user interface. I was wondering if it's possible to enable / disable the meter via `JavaScript`?