# Electron desktop application that support high FPS animation

Tags: image, electron

I simulate a high FPS camera and was requested for a desktop app that supports screen drawing in 100 Hertz.

Now it's implemented in .Net (winforms) and I want to learn a new technology. Therefore, I need to show that there aren't performance issues using Electron framework with JS UI.

I searched quite a bit and the max FPS where 60.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since Electron is using Chromium for rendering, it should be possible.

You could check this by setting the show FPS flag and running a short test:

[Show FPS meter Chrome 33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038065/show-fps-meter-chrome-33)